# Flutter - Reuse same custom widget class for instances appear not at same time

Tags: flutter

In shorter word, my question is how to call child's `initState()` again on parent's `setState()`.

I need to reuse a widget class for multiple instances. I need the widgets to appear in turn like below where I can use `setState()` to switch between them.

```
bool showthefirstone = true;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
  TheWidget it = showthefirstone ? TheWidget(...) : TheWidget(..);
  ...
}
```

The later one's `initState()` is not called. No problem showing them both together along at the same time. The issue only occurs upon `setState()`.

For those who don't understand, this trigger the change

```
setState((){showthefirstone = !showthefirstone})
```

Comment: Where is the trigger to change your widgets? Is a button, data response...

Comment: I don't understand correctly, what condition do you want to call setState? Whenever a condition is met? If so, use didUpdateWidget and check the current widget object against the previous one to see what has changed.

Comment: @Chance the setState change the boolean value. i made my question simplest

Comment: The answer is there is no way to call initState for state already assembled. For that there is didUpdateWidget, it is a lifecycle method that is called whenever the constructor receives a new value, so the widget object will change and you can call setState from inside him.

Comment: @Chance ok. so how to use same widget class multiple times at different time without call setstate from the widget class itself?

Comment: Okay, does setState come from inside TheWidget widget? I'm having a hard time understanding how your widget changes state.

Comment: @Chance yes sure. i just want to reuse same widget class and rebuild the widget without need to define that same class in two different files

Comment: @Chance i had a workaround. i just need a proper solution if any before go for it

Comment: Same answer with different question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69034391/force-rebuild-of-a-stateful-child-widget-in-flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same answer with different question. My question is more generic. At least works for my case.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70789848/1297048